# What service controls when network connections are discovered?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, windows-services

I have recently upgraded to Win10 v.2004 and while the update itself seems to have gone without a hitch, I have a (bad?) habit of checking Services after a major update and doing some tweaks. Usually this is fine, I know what I can disable or set to manual start without any issues.

But this time I've unwittingly created an issue where network connectivity is not restored before quite some time after logging on. So when I launch the browser the first thing I do after a boot, it's not yet connected to the internet, and the state of the network icon in the tray is still "discovering". This is a wired connection so usually it's connected already before I log in (on the lock screen).

I assume I've set some service to manual and so it needs to be triggered by some activity before it connects properly.

[image: Identifying network status]

So my question is; what service controls the checking of network connectivity on Windows startup?

I've listed my current services and their state here:
https://pastebin.com/nT3WqR2D

Specs:

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.19041 Build 19041
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz, 4001 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
Product Type    Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
PNP Device ID   PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_15A1&SUBSYS_15A11849&REV_00\3&11583659&0&C8
```

Comment: What are the exact models of your computer and network adapter?

Comment: @harrymc; I've updated the post with system info. I thought it might not depend on my exact specs.

Comment: The specs may help (or not). If this is not a self-built computer, what is its model (computer, not components).

Comment: It's a self-built, ca 2015, upgraded a bit later. I could give a the output from Speccy if that would help? :)

Comment: See the [following list](https://mywindowshub.com/restoring-default-services-windows-10-technical-preview/) for services. The names of all network services start with "Network". If System Restore is activated, it might be simpler to rollback to before you did your tweaks.